# What does the word "fancy" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does fancy mean "like" or "desire to have something"? If my sentence doesn't have something desired, will it be correct if I say "I do not fancy it" as "I don't like it"? Or "I do fancy it" = "I like it"  or another example "I don't fancy that team" = I like that team / "I do fancy that team" =  I like that team as there is no desire, will it be corrected?

Answer (score 1):

If you **fancy** *something*, you **want to have it** or **to do it**.

So, if there is something you don't desire, you can say "I don't fancy doing it", just like "I don't want to do it" (you can also use this construction with a noun: *I don't fancy a drink* *= I don't want a drink*). In this case, if you say "I don't like doing it/to do it", it's OK grammatically but it means a different thing because "to like" is not "to want". Note that this meaning of "fancy" is mostly British.

However, if you **fancy** *someone*, you feel attracted to them, that is you **like** them (especially in a sexual way).

Comment: If you *fancy* a horse, it means you think it will win the race.

Comment: What if I use fancy as verb. Example - I don't fancy that team = I don't like that team.

Answer (score 0):

> "I do not fancy it" = "I don't like it"?
>
> "I do fancy it" = "I like it"

You are correct.

**fancy** in this sense:  [TDF](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fancy)

> a. A capricious liking or inclination b. A romantic liking or interest